# How to resize UIWebView content to specific dimensions?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I have an application requirement of displaying custom ads in it so I decided to use UIWebView and load specific url with 468x60 ads generated in it. It works like charm, except one thing: loaded ad is too big (naturally) for 320px iPhone screen and I am unable to force it to shrink a litle bit.

What could I possibly do about it? Maybe there are some Javascript/CSS/HTML stuff I could do in ad page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checkout the "viewport" meta-tag.  It'll let you tell the phone what the width of the page is and you can also set the initial zoom level.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html

Answer (score 2):

UIWebView has a property called scalesPageToFit, or you could clip the image to the required dimensions, or resize the property to the correct size before downloading and displaying.